# Button not working to get data from one database and add it into new databse

Tags: javascript, php, html

I new to learn PHP,HTML,CSS and JAVASCRIPT, and battle with this code.  I have tried it without and with form, but when click on button,(with form) it is running for 2 seconds and it does not update my new database.  With out form nothing is happening.
I know there are problems with my code, learning and fixing them.

```
    <?php include_once 'header.php'?> 

    <form id="basicForm" action="updateDatabase.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="basicForm">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
        
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-25">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <h3 class="card-title">Update Database</h3>
                                </div>  
                                 <div class="card-body">
                                    <p>
                                            <button position="relative" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-danger btn-lg c1" id="homeDB">Home DB</button>&nbsp;
                                            <span id="homeupdate"></span>  
                                            <span id="loaders1" style="display:none;">
                                                <img alt="" src="dist/img/loader11.gif">                   
                                            </span>
                                        </p>
                                        <p>
                                           <button position="relative" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-success btn-lg c1" id="workdb">Work DB</button>&nbsp;
                                            <span id="workupdate"></span>  
                                            <span id="loaders2" style="display:none;">
                                                <img alt="" src="dist/img/loader11.gif">                   
                                            </span>
                                            
                                        </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#homeDB').on('click', function() {


                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'db.php',
                    // dataType: 'json',
                    data:{db:"homeDB"},
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $("#loaders1").show();
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                        $("#loaders1").hide();
                    },
                    success:function(data) {
                        
                        $("#homeupdate").html("Databasis Opgedateer");
                          
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        $("#homeupdate").html(error);
                    }
                });

            });


            $('#workdb').on('click', function() {


                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'db.php',
                    // dataType: 'json',
                    data:{db:"workdb"},
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $("#loaders2").show();
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                        $("#loaders2").hide();
                    },
                    success:function(data) {
                        
                        $("#workupdate").html("Databasis Opgedateer");
                        
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        $("#workupdate").html(error);
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>
        
      
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
              
                // Basic Form
                jQuery("#basicForm").validate({
                    highlight: function(element) {
                        jQuery(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
                    },
                    success: function(element) {
                        jQuery(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                    }
                });
              
                // Error Message In One Container
                jQuery("#basicForm2").validate({
                    errorLabelContainer: jQuery("#basicForm2 div.errorForm")
                });
              
                // With Checkboxes and Radio Buttons
                
                jQuery('#genderError').attr('for','gender');
                jQuery('#intError').attr('for','int[]');
                
                jQuery("#basicForm3").validate({
                    highlight: function(element) {
                        jQuery(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
                    },
                    success: function(element) {
                        jQuery(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                    }
                });
                
                jQuery("#basicForm4").validate({
                    highlight: function(element) {
                        jQuery(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
                    },
                    success: function(element) {
                        jQuery(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                    },
                    ignore: null
                });
                
                // Validation with select boxes
                jQuery("#flowers, #fruits").select2({
                    minimumResultsForSearch: -1
                });
              
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
<?php include_once 'footer.php'?>
```

Comment: Just FYI: forms with the enctype `multipart/form-data` are generally used to upload files. That aside - where is the `db.php` code that **should** process the POST requests? Are the javascript functions invoked OK? Do you see POST requests in the network tab of the console?

Comment: a `button` has a default action of `submitting` a form so unless you explicitly prevent that default behaviour ( hint: `event.preventDefault()` ) there will be a race condition between the jQuery code and the normal form submission. You can add a `type` attribute to the button, viz: `<button type='button' ... >` etc

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the `button` and assign it a `type='button'` attribute you should be able to observe (in the console) that each button now fires the ajax request and the form is no longer submitted as per the default behaviour.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#homeDB').on('click', function() {
    console.log(this)
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'db.php',
      // dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        db: "homeDB"
      },
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#loaders1").show();
      },
      complete: function() {
        $("#loaders1").hide();
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#homeupdate").html("Databasis Opgedateer");

      },
      error: function(error) {
        $("#homeupdate").html(error);
      }
    });
  });


  $('#workdb').on('click', function() {
    console.log(this)
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'db.php',
      // dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        db: "workdb"
      },
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#loaders2").show();
      },
      complete: function() {
        $("#loaders2").hide();
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#workupdate").html("Databasis Opgedateer");
      },
      error: function(error) {
        $("#workupdate").html(error);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form id="basicForm" action="updateDatabase.php" method="post" name="basicForm">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content-wrapper">

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-25">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">Update Database</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <p>
                  <button type='button' position="relative" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-danger btn-lg c1" id="homeDB">Home DB</button>&nbsp;
                  <span id="homeupdate"></span>
                  <span id="loaders1" style="display:none;">
                    <img alt="" src="dist/img/loader11.gif">
                  </span>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <button type='button' position="relative" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-success btn-lg c1" id="workdb">Work DB</button>&nbsp;
                  <span id="workupdate"></span>
                  <span id="loaders2" style="display:none;">
                    <img alt="" src="dist/img/loader11.gif">
                  </span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, @professor Abronsius, I did add the console, but it still do not work, when I click the button.  I think it does not see db.php (it is the same folder)not sure if this part is correct to see the db.php file.        url: 'db.php',

Comment: open the console before making the request and monitor the network tab. Report back any oberservations / errors etc

Comment: I have open the console and when I open the page it is showing that it has open the page with about 800ms, and under it is shows a a lot of files.  When I click on any one of the two buttons, nothing changed.   At the bottom of network, there are two other info.  1. console that show 41 messages and issues that have two errors in it, but that is something else.

Comment: specifically it is the `Fetch/XHR` ( chrome ) or `XHR` ( Firefox ) portion of the `network` tab that will show the traffic. Any http response that is not 200 perhaps requires closer inspection. If you run the snippet above and open the console, go to network and choose `fetch/xhr` or `xhr` depending upon browser you should see calls made to `db.php` with different payloads

Comment: Did do what you said, but there is nothing happening at all. My db.php is in the same folder

Comment: If you run the snippet, open the console and inspect thenetwork requests you **WILL** see network requests being made. I **cannot** know how you have implemented any changes unless you amend the question to show any updates you have made or create a new [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and share the full code ( with sensitive data redacted ). The above snippet does send successful http requests!